# C++, ternary operator operand evaluation rules

Tags: c++

Lets say i have following code:

```
std::vector<T> R;
if (condition) R = generate();
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    const auto &r = (R.empty() ? generate() : R);
}
```

It appears that generate is called regardless of `R.empty()`.  Is that standard behavior?

Comment: No, that is not standard behavior.  Are you 100% positive that this is what is going on?  As in, you have run a debugger, you can see it checking `R.empty()`, and you're watching it call `generate()` anyway?

Comment: @templatetypedef yes, absolutely sure, triple checked

Comment: Can you please post a minimal, complete, self-contained, reproducible test case so that we can play around with it?  `generate()` should not be called if `R.empty()` is false, so I suspect that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to me that your code calls potentially calls `generate()` outside the loop. Could that be what you are observing?

Comment: any UB in the neighborhood?

Comment: @Nik in some cases, R may be populated outside the loop, to save expense of generating data inside loops.  However, generate gets called regardless

Comment: @Anycorn: [show me](http://ideone.com/qiJaQM)

Comment: @templatetypedef will try, the code is not easy to extract

Comment: @Anycorn: I know you answered already, but are you REALLY sure that your vector is *not* empty? If you are really sure, then you might have UB due to some other part of your code

Comment: @AndyProwl yes.  i'll run valgrind, see if it may be some memory issue

Answer (score 23):

From Paragraph 5.16/1 of the C++ 11 Standard:

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It is evaluated and if it is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression, otherwise that of the third expression. **Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated**. Every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the second or third expression.