# How does the conditional/ternary operator work? C++

Tags: c++

What would be the literal translation for the following code. Also, please explain what it meaning and the different ways of using this operator.

```
int i = 1, j = 2; 
 cout << ( i > j ? i : j ) << " is greater." << endl;
```

Any other useful or additional information about the ternary operator that will help me understand it better would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is homework? I am sure that it is

Comment: It does seem like it but it's not. If you still don't believe me, could you please just explain how it works? And the different ways of using it?

Comment: If you don't have a [decent book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) yet then it's probably time to consider getting one - this sort of basic stuff is covered in the first few chapters of any good introductory book.

Comment: Google ternray operator - will that do (PS: I do not believe you as it is a Sunday and this is a basic question)

Comment: Haha, you sure you don't know this? Because googling it will show million examples of it.

Comment: searching on SO might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763054/c-ternary-operator-operand-evaluation-rules/14763151#14763151

Comment: Okay people. This is not homework, I'm just learning C++ by myself because it's fun. My school doesn't even offer anything to do with programming. I just read somewhere that this is the best place to ask questions.

Comment: @Wulfinite - Searching the internet/reading the book is quicker. Besides these questions do turn on Sunday and sort of get people thinking they have to turn in their homework for tomorrow.

Comment: @Wulfinite where did you read that?  Also, if you like reading stuff, try clickign on the 'Help' menu item above and reading the site policy etc.

Comment: Any book you people would recommend for beginners?

Comment: @EdHeal yes, but if you can con those naive slaves on SO to write you a unique answer, it will not match the net copypasta submissions from the other students.

Comment: I already posted a link for you for a definitive C++ book list in the comments above. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @MartinJames - Exactly my point.

Comment: lol 'book you people would recommend' is specifically off-topic for SO, as you would have known if you had read the policy/roles/guides before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( i > j ? i : j )
```

basically means:

if `(i > j) is true` return `i`, else return `j`

---

**Side note:** This is very similar to MS Excel's if-formula